# NSString:componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet inclusive

Tags: objective-c, tokenize, shunting-yard, nscharacterset

```
NSString *infix = @"4+23-54/543*23";
NSCharacterSet *operatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-*/"];
NSArray *tokens = [infix componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:operatorSet];
```

`tokens` returns:

> [@"4", @"23", @"54", @"543", @"23"]

I am trying to implement Shunting Yard in Objective-C. How can I tokenize the infix string with the operator set without removing the operator set itself from the tokenization?

What I need:

> [@"4", @"+", @"23", @"-", @"54", @"/", @"543", @"*", @"23"]

Comment: I guess, `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` is just the wrong tool for this. Have a look at NSScanner.

Comment: Yes, oddly the function you desire seems to be absent from the NSString functions.

Comment: NSCharacterSet has `inverseSet` So you can separate by the inverse... but you probably lose necessary ordering.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use regEx, you could insert a space before and after the operators and then split the string by spaces.

> ```
> NSString *infix = @"4+23-54/543*23";
> NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([+,*,/,-])" options:0 error:NULL];
> NSString *newString = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:infix options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, infix.length) withTemplate:@" $1 $2"];
> NSArray *tokens = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
> ```